# Runtime.getRuntime().exec( ... ) runs javac, javah but not java under Java 8 + NetBeans:

Tags: java

I want to run inside  NetBeans + Java 8  a program from inside another one with the help of Runtime.getRuntime().exec( ... ) . It correctly runs javac and javah but not java. Your help will highly appreciated.

This is the program that I want to run

```
package Programs;


public class AddTwoIntegers {

    private static Integer addTwoIntegers(Integer a, Integer b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer a = 5;
        Integer b = 8;
        Integer result = addTwoIntegers(a, b);
        System.out.println(a.toString()
                .concat(  " + ")
                .concat(  b.toString() )
                .concat( " = " )
                .concat(  result.toString()));
    }

}
```

This is the program that   pretends to run the previous class:

```
/*

This program is intended to run a java program from another java program
It runs javac and javah but not java.

 */
package Programs;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

//import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
// java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class JavacTest {

    private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
        String line;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(name + " " + line);
        }
    }

    private static void runProcess(String command) throws Exception {
        Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        printLines(command + " stdin:", pro.getInputStream());
        printLines(command + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
        printLines(command + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
        //Take your time
        pro.waitFor();
        System.out.println(command + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
    }

    private static void runProcess2(String [] command) throws Exception {
        Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        printLines(Arrays.toString(command) + " stdin:", pro.getInputStream());
        printLines(Arrays.toString(command) + " stdout:", pro.getInputStream());
        printLines(Arrays.toString(command) + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
        //Take your time
        pro.waitFor();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(command) + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
    } 




    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("\nCompiling with javac: .java -> .class");
            runProcess("/home/jose/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/javac    
/home/jose/NetBeansProjects/eJVolu17P/src/Programs/AddTwoIntegers.java");
            //take your time
            //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            System.out.println("\n\nShowing the bytecode content of the .class file with javap");
            runProcess("/home/jose/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/javap  -c 
/home/jose/NetBeansProjects/eJVolu17P/src/Programs/AddTwoIntegers.class");
            System.out.println("\n\nWorking Directory = " +
              System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            System.out.println("\n\nRunning the .class file with java");

            //runProcess("/home/jose/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java   -cp    
/home/jose/NetBeansProjects/eJVolu17P/build/classes/Programs/AddTwoIntegers");
            //runProcess("/home/jose/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java   -cp     /build/classes/Programs/AddTwoIntegers");
            String[] Commands  = new String[3];
            Commands[0] = "/home/jose/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java";
            Commands[1] = "-classpath";
                    Commands[2] = "/home/jose/NetBeansProjects/eJVolu17P/build/classes/Programs/AddTwoIntegers";
            runProcess2(Commands );
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: “It correctly runs javac and javah but not java.” How can you tell?  Perhaps you should include stderr output in your question so we know more about what’s going wrong.

Comment: You should run the program by something like
/home/jose/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java   -cp /home/jose/NetBeansProjects/eJVolu17P/build/classes/ Programs.AddTwoIntegers
Try it and see if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the program by something like
/home/jose/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java   -cp /home/jose/NetBeansProjects/eJVolu17P/build/classes/ Programs.AddTwoIntegers
Try it and see if this works.

The class path should point to the parent folder of package.Java class name. Check if that works.

Comment: Right! The output of the called program appears in stdin. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had a misconception: the argument of .exec(java ...) had 3 tokens, but after thinking of the solution proposed by Ayusman, it became clear that it consists of 4 tokens, such as it is specified in the following final solution:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;



//import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class JavacTest {

    private static void printLines(String name, InputStream ins)
            throws Exception {
        String line;
        BufferedReader in 
                = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(name + " " + line);
        }
    }

    private static void runProcess(String command) 
            throws Exception {
        Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        printLines(command 
                + " stdin:", pro.getInputStream());
        printLines(command 
                + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
        //Take your time
        pro.waitFor();
        System.out.println(command 
                + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
    }

    private static void runProcess2(String [] command) 
            throws Exception {
        Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        printLines(Arrays.toString(command) 
                + " stdin:", pro.getInputStream());
        printLines(Arrays.toString(command) 
                + " stderr:", pro.getErrorStream());
        //Take your time
        pro.waitFor();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(command) 
                + " exitValue() " + pro.exitValue());
    } 



   /*
    Note about paths:


    When NetBeans runs a  .java  program, the compiled class  .class  is put in a 
    subfolder of  build in the same folder of the project:  
    build/classes/Programs. 
    When a  .java program is run with javac from inside another master
    .java program, the corresponding  .class file is put in the 
    same folder as the master  .java program.
    */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("\nCompiling with javac: .java -> .class");
            runProcess("/home/jose/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/javac  "
                    + "  /home/jose/NetBeansProjects/eJVolu17P/src"
                    + "/Programs/AddTwoIntegers.java");
            //take your time
            //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);


            System.out.println("\n\nShowing the bytecode "
                    + "content of the .class file with javap");
            runProcess("/home/jose/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/javap  "
                    + "-c /home/jose/NetBeansProjects/eJVolu17P/src"
                    + "/Programs/AddTwoIntegers.class");
            System.out.println("\n\nWorking Directory = " +
                System.getProperty("user.dir"));
            //TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);


            System.out.println("\n\nRunning the .class file with java");
            String[] Commands  = new String[4];
            //Path to java
            Commands[0] = "/home/jose/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java"; 
             //Command: claspath
            Commands[1] = "-cp";
            //Path to parent folder of  package with the .java program = Programs
            Commands[2] = "/home/jose/NetBeansProjects/eJVolu17P/src/";
            //Used package + name of compiled class without suffix .class
            Commands[3] = "Programs.AddTwoIntegers";
            runProcess2(Commands );
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```